# What is the difference between transcendental state of mind and Nirvana?

Tags: nirvana

Some yogis of India believe in transcendental state of mind. However I saw no such reference in the teachings of Buddha.
So , what is difference between transcendental state of mind and Nirvana?
(Assuming Nirvana is the Buddhist state of mind)

Answer (score 3):

Nirvana is not a state of mind but is an element the transcendental mind has sense contact with.

As for "transcendental" mind, the Pali is "[lokuttara](https://suttacentral.net/define/lokuttara)"; which literally means "above/beyond the world".

> Thus you should train yourselves: 'We will listen when discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their meaning, transcendent (lokuttara), connected with emptiness — are being recited. We will lend ear, will set our hearts on knowing them, will regard these teachings as worth grasping & mastering.' That's how you should train yourselves.
>
> [Ani Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn20/sn20.007.than.html)